# Firebase - Is there a way to get only documents with an array field which contains a certain value?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a simple collection `Cats`:

```
Cats:
  Meowy:
    colors: ['orange', 'white']
  Purro:
    colors: ['black', 'orange']
  Bob:
    colors: ['black']
```

How can I query only the documents that their `colors` field contains orange (in JavaScript)?

Comment: There should be _array contains_ method. But you have to call it for each field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems it can work however I haven't tried in my local. Also check the firebase documentation :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web_3

```
var catRef = db.collection("Cats");

catRef.where('colors', 'array-contains',
    'orange');
```